# Gridview row back color not changing on text change event Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Everybody. I know there are lots of similar question but still I am asking for it because the earlier query doesn't meet my requirement. I have look for it, please don't mark it as duplicate. I am trying to change the row color of the Gridview where txt_Id.Text is equal to the Id of the Gridview row. Below is the code :

```
protected void lnkSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
        GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView4.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        txt_Id.Text = Id.ToString();

        foreach (GridViewRow row1 in GridView4.Rows)
        {
            if (txt_Id.Text != "")
            {
                if (row1.Cells[1].Text.Equals(txt_Id.Text))
                {
                    row1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    row1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: @ TaW I made the changes. Thanks.

Comment: is this gridview present in a updatepanel?

Comment: @ Ahsan yup I am using panel for it : <asp:Panel ID="pnlRetrieve" runat="server" Visible="true"> .... </asp:Panel>

Comment: It is working just fine. Maybe the contents of `Cells[1]` is not what you expect?